# What are the available appraoches we can follow to test & debug our Office/SharePoint Add-ins without having to use Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, azureservicebus, servicebus

I am working on developing SharePoint Add-ins for our SharePoint online sites. The Add-ins are mainly Provider hosted add-ins that contain WCFs to implement Remote Event Receivers.

Now, to debug these Provider Hosted add-ins, I use to have an Azure Service Bus connection string, which I created using my free Azure account subscription couple of months ago. Where inside my Visual Studio project, I add the Azure Service Bus connection string inside the Project properties, as follows:

[image: entering connection string]

Now my test Azure account has expired, and many customers we are dealing with do not have an Azure subscription. Most of them have VMs exposed to the internet to host the SharePoint Add-ins.

**What are the alternatives we can use for debugging our SharePoint Add-ins, if we do not have Azure Service Bus?**

For example, are any of these options valid?

1. Since we have a VM which is exposed to the internet (such as Azure VM), can we create a Service Bus functionality inside this Azure VM, which will allow us to debug the code?
2. If the answer to the first question is yes, then where inside my Visual Studio project should I specify the connection string? It seems that the option to specify a Service Bus is explicitly for Azure Service Bus, as shown in the above picture.

Can anyone help me in figuring out these points?

Answer (score 1):

As of January 2017, SharePoint supports webhooks which are easier to develop and debug. If you cannot use Azure Service Bus, which [Microsoft's docs identify as the primary method for debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/debug-and-troubleshoot-a-remote-event-receiver-in-a-sharepoint-add-in), then you will need to migrate your code to use webhooks instead.

Here's the [Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/overview-sharepoint-webhooks).

Here's a [Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/get-started-webhooks) doc.

From the overview:

> Webhooks are easier to develop and consume than Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) services used by SharePoint add-in remote event receivers.

Comment: i already know about web hooks, but they do not support synchronous operations such as (adding & editing), and i am synchronous operations heavily inside my code, to cancel the adding and editing operations if they do not match certain critirias... so that why i chose Remote Event Receivers,over web hooks...